# fill list box with each day from date to date vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, listbox, fill

I want to add dates for everyday in list box since 1/1/2014 until the day when someone load my form,as the following:

1/Jan/2014
2/Jan/2014
3/Jan/2014
..
..
..
today's date

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Public Sub Form_Load()
    FillList()
End Sub

Private Sub FillList()
    Dim dWorkDate As Date = CDate("01.01.2014")
    While dWorkDate < Date.Today
        myListBox.Items.Add(dWorkDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))
        dWorkDate = dWorkDate.AddDays(1)
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: It's type-conversion. Please look here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- Your form is name is `Form1`
- You have a combobox control named `ComboBox1` (You can change this to a listbox, although I would recommend a comobox for ease of use and display)

These are the default names given by VB when you insert your form and controls in it. Simply copy paste the sub into the `Class Form1`

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim D As Date
        Dim TD As Date
        Dim Count As Integer
        TD = FormatDateTime(Today, DateFormat.GeneralDate)

        D = #1/1/2014#
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(FormatDateTime(D, DateFormat.GeneralDate).ToString)
        Count = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, D, TD)

        For i As Integer = 0 To Count - 1
            D = D.AddDays(1)
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(FormatDateTime(D, DateFormat.GeneralDate).ToString)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Output:
[image]